# Using only the Meteor frontend part

Tags: javascript, meteor

is there a possibility to only use the frontend part of meteor and serve the files via a static vanish server?

I want to build a web app which uses an existing PHP REST API, but I lice the reactivity and the tempting of meteor, which I can get with the Session variable.

If there is a simple way to separate the frontend parts from the back so that I can easily serve them, would be awesome. Especially the web socket is not needed. Because there will be no after connection to the deliver server.

Comment: You like the reactivity, as in css/template updates pushed to the client? How are you going to achieve that if you have no means to push something to a client or make the client aware of a change?

Comment: i would make http calls, and then use the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done. For meteor to get live updates you need a connection to a server of some sort to relay the message down.

There are a couple of methods you could use, however

If you like the DOM reactivity and all the data is locally hosted/you would like to fetch it from php would like to use it in a static application something like [angular](http://angularjs.org/) or [react](http://facebook.github.io/react/) could help you.

The other is you could use a deployed instance of an application & have it stored on a static/varnish server. But use DDP to have the server relay data. See http://arunoda.me/blog/hosting-meteor-apps-as-a-client.html

Comment: i dont want the reactivity from the database, but from the session.

Comment: If you see the second one with arunoda's blog you could get it done there. You don't have to use a valid DDP proxy. Mind that you can still use collections locally without passing on the collection name, e.g `var collection = new Meteor.Collection()`. You you don't only have to use Session. Also have a look at https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data to help you use an offline mode (at the moment) and use full offline data when the project is done.

Comment: thanks, yeah angualr and react is nice, but meteor gives me all the templating stuff as well and nicely packaged. it has basically all the functionality i would build then with grunt.js and require.js.
so an easy way to deatach the frontend parts from the backend would be awesome.

Comment: thanks for your feedback Akshat. the problem is that you cant remove core packages, like live data, so he always trys to connect to the server via socket.js

Comment: You can't remove them but meteor can work fine in client mode, if you give it a non existent ddp server it will still try to connect and nothing will happen to your client side apps. The offline mode simulation will help you make sure it doesn't keep trying to reconnect